# How to upgrade OpenSSL for PHP 5.3.10

Tags: php, ssl, tls1.2, php-openssl

We have PHP 5.3.10. 
It is using SSL Version => OpenSSL/0.9.8t.
We need to upgrade system for TLS 1.1. . It means we need OpenSSL 1.0.1 or higher version.

I could not find what is the highest version of OpenSSL compatible with this version of PHP. And can I just replace dll, and adjust ini files to use it? Or should I do anything else to upgrade it?

If anyone knows good tutorial, it could be helpful. I could not find any.

Comment: PHP 5.3.10 release date was **02 February 2012** :( you really should update to a newer version (one that comes with a newer version of OpenSSL)

Comment: We need rewrite our php code to make it work with newer version. We are going to do it, but we will need to start using TLS 1.1 before that. Can I just replace dll in php ext folder?

Comment: It will probably not work...